# Domain with multiply condition

Tags: odoo

I have a domain like this

```
 [('product_id.fix', '!=', False), '|', ('trigger', '=', 'auto'), ('product_id.active', '=', True), ('company_id', '=', 1), ('qty_forecast', '<', 0)]
```

and I tried it like this

```
 [ '|',('product_id.fix', '!=', False), ('trigger', '=', 'auto'), ('product_id.active', '=', True), ('company_id', '=', 1), ('qty_forecast', '<', 0)]
```

and my search not getting any result

if i add to domain only `[('product_id.fix', '!=', False)]` then it return some record.

But basically, I want that search would return any record that suits this part `[('product_id.fix', '!=', False)]` and plus `('trigger', '=', 'auto'), ('product_id.active', '=', True), ('company_id', '=', 1), ('qty_forecast', '<', 0)`

so first search need to find all records that where `product_id.fix != False` and then all records with other conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write it like your second expample, you would get:

> (condition-1 OR condition-2) AND all-other-conditions

to get:

> condition-1 OR all-other conditions

, you should write it like this:

```
[ 
    '|',
    ('product_id.fix', '!=', False), 
    (
        ('trigger', '=', 'auto'), 
        ('product_id.active', '=', True), 
        ('company_id', '=', 1), 
        ('qty_forecast', '<', 0)
    )
]
```